# Can MSE be seen as a type NLL loss for BNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, bayesian-networks

I am doing a BNN for regression. When defining the loss function, Negative Log Likelihood loss (NLL loss) are highly involved no matter which method for BNN. I see some people would directly use a MSE loss as the NLL loss, some people would define there own NLL loss. So my question is, can MSE be seen as a type of NLL loss for BNN? and what are the differences for these two losses?

I have tried using MSE loss for the BNN, it works, even though I do not fully understand it is appropriate or not. I have tried `torch.nn.NLLLoss`, but it does not work.

Comment: is it a regression or a classification task? This will decide your error (= cost) function

Comment: it is a regression task.

Answer (score 1):

The MSE is the NLL with a constant variance (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317988)).

Thus, the MSE

[image: Loss with MSE]

is equivalent to the (Gaussian) log-likelihood

[image: Loss with NLL]

where `I` is the identity matrix (1 on the diagonal).

In PyTorch you can use the [GaussianNLLLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GaussianNLLLoss.html#torch.nn.GaussianNLLLoss), to pass the variance.

[image credits](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/distill_bayes_net/public/)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a regression task, there's nothing wrong with using MSE as the cost function. It doesn't particularly depend on the neural networks or in this case BNNs. The reason you were unable to use *torch.nn.NLLLoss* here is because it expects class indices as the target/label instead you are providing continuous variables.

As for using the MSE loss as the NLL loss, I'm not sure what you tried to mean by that. The negative log-likelihood (NLL) loss is viewed as a cost function only for classification problems in [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) however it's not really the case. I believe this [issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611986/how-nll-loss-is-used-for-regression) would give you a clear explanation.